# Finding Repeated Digits and Commas in JSON Text File using Regex

Tags: json, regex, sublimetext3

What sort of Regex would I use to match and replace a repeated sequence that goes [Digits][Comma] using Regex for Sublime Text?

For example, it would need to match this example string in my JSON file:

```
        "user_exp": 12, 12,
```

and:

```
        "unit_exp": 18, 18,
```

I need the regular expression to match the digits, such as ""user_exp": 12, 12," and then a second regular expression that lets Sublime Text change that line of text to: "user_exp": 12,

But it should not match lines that don't have these double repeated digits like:

```
        "user_exp": 12,
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

Find: `(".+?":)( \d+,)\1`

Replace with: `$1$2`